# Showing a overlaying menu when tab bar item is clicked - IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

Thanks for reading my question!

I have a 5-part tabbar which I use for app navigation, the center tab is covered by a `UIButton` and is slightly larger (much like the instagram app). This works fine.

But what I want is the far right tab bar item to show a overlaying menu when clicked. I don't want it to switch to a `viewcontroller` with a menu. I want the menu to be displayed no matter which of the other views you're in at the moment. So I want it to act much like a button which is in the tabbar. But I have no idea how to go about doing this.

Should I use a overlaying button over the `tabbaritem` or should I catch the tabbarclick, but how can I prevent the view from changing in that case?

Thanks you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `UITabBarDelegate`. Then override `tabBar:didSelectItem:` and implement your custom displaying here. See below for reference

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Then i would just make a custom `UIView` and fade it in when that specific tagged `UITabBarItem` is pressed.

Comment: It works good thanks! Just one thing: When I press the tabbar item it still switches viewcontroller. Is there any way to prevent this?